# dart does not know that a variable is not null

Tags: dart

Dart code:

```
if (v != null) {
  v.add(5);
}
```

v is not null because of the if condition.
but dart compiler complains that v can be null, and need to use v!.

```
if (v != null) {
  v!.add(5);
}
```

But the following code:

```
if (v is TypeFoo) {
   execute(v as TypeFoo);
}
```

Here the compiler is smart, and says that cast is not necessary.

Comment: if v is a property, it might have a getter, and be a different value every time.

Comment: Almost certainly your first example involves a non-local variable and your last example involves a local variable, which are not equivalent situations.  If that's not the case, provide complete examples that reproduce the problem, and I'll reopen this.